# parse url with php to remove or alter sections

Tags: php, parsing, url, url-parsing

Let's say you have two urls.

```
http://testing.org/directory/index.php/arg1/arg2
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => testing.org [path] => /directory/index.php/arg1/arg2 )
```

Or something like this:

```
http://testing.org/index.php/arg1/arg2
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => testing.org [path] => /index.php/arg1/arg2 )
```

I know you can break the url down with parse_array().  When I do that, the path is everything after 'testing.org'.  In the first example path variable 1 in the array is 'directory' but in the second example path variable 1 is 'index.php'.

I am trying to figure out hot to do 2 separate things.  Firstly remove everything after index.php but I keep fumbling the ball. Also, how would I remove the '/directory/' from the first url?

But I'd also like to learn how replace a section of the path too.

Comment: Can you show your code and explain exactly where it is not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and regex to accomplish this. The below regular expression will strip out everything after the `index.php` in the URL path.

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$scriptname = preg_replace('#(index\.php)/.*#', '$1', $parts['path']);
$result = $parts['scheme'].'://'. $parts['host'] . $scriptname;
```

For the two URLs given the question, the output would be as follows:

```
http://testing.org/directory/index.php
http://testing.org/index.php
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/70746)

Comment: Thanks for helping a non-programmer out!

Comment: @user2070436: Start learning then! It's fun. Anyway, I'm glad to have been of help. Cheers!